# Eliminate the [skills] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[skills](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skills) is undefined.  It has two questions, both generally about acquiring skills.  Acquiring skills seems off-topic.  The tag doesn't add anything to either question.  Should it be eliminated?

Answer (score 1):

The tag is useless. I removed it.